# PG syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, syntax-error

I've been trying to convert the [fedena project](https://github.com/projectfedena/fedena) built on ruby on rails for my school from mySQL to postgreSQL for heroku deployment and ran into the following error:

**Showing app/views/class_timings/index.html.erb where line #40 raised:**

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: SELECT `batches`.*,CONCAT(courses.code,'-',batches.name) as ...
                        ^

: SELECT `batches`.*,CONCAT(courses.code,'-',batches.name) as course_full_name FROM "batches"   INNER JOIN "courses" ON "courses".id = "batches".course_id  WHERE ("batches"."is_deleted" = 'f' AND "batches"."is_active" = 't')  ORDER BY course_full_name
```

**Extracted source (around line #40):**

```
37:     <label ><%= t('select_a_batch') %>:</label>
38:     <div class="text-input-bg">
39:       <%= select :batch, :id,
40:         @batches.map {|b| [b.full_name, b.id] },
41:         {:prompt => "#{t('common')}"},
42:         {:onchange => "#{remote_function(
43:         :url => { :action => 'show' },
44:         :with => "'batch_id='+value",
45:         :before => "Element.show('loader')",
46:         :success => "Element.hide('loader')"
47:         )}"} %>
```

Obviously, I'm new to programming! Please help.

The controller:

**class_timings_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @batches = Batch.active
    @class_timings = ClassTiming.find(:all,:conditions => { :batch_id => nil,:is_deleted=>false}, :order =>'start_time ASC')
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the backtick quotes ` and the `CONCAT` function are non-standard SQL.

If you really want to quote table-names you'll need to use double-quotes. There is a text-concatenation operator you'll want in Postgresql called `||`.

So you'll have something like:

```
SELECT "batches".*, (courses.code || '-' || "batches"."name") as course_full_name ...
```

Be consistent - if you are quoting tables names in some places, quote them everywhere.

This is going to be slow going until you understand the syntax of both databases at at least a basic level. Presumably there's not too much raw SQL since you're using rails though.

Tip: set aside a couple of hours and skim through the manuals of both systems. At least you'll know where to look to check details then.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! thumbs up